# Extract Style Attributes from Style[]

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, formatting

Can you extract the Style attributes from a variable. For example:

```
var = Style["aString", Bold, 24]
```

You can get back "aString" by using ToString[var] but I am not able to get the attributes {Bold, 24}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine its `FullForm`:

```
var = Style["aString", Bold, 24];
var // InputForm

(* Out: Style["aString", Bold, 24] *)
```

Exactly as you typed in.  You can manipulate it just as you would any Mathematica expression.  For example:

```
List @@ Rest[var]

(* Out: {Bold, 24} *)
```

Comment: Did not think of replacing the Head on var. Perfect, thank you so much. Peter

Comment: There ought to be a way to compare `Style["aString", Bold, 24]` and `Style["aString", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 24]`...

Comment: @rm-rf Isn't there? `var2 = Style["aString", Bold, 24];
var1 = Style["aString", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 24];
OrderedQ[{var2, var1}]` returns a reasonable result. Do you want `var1` and `var2` to be the same?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, the same. I understand why _Mathematica_ sees them differently and why `SameQ` is `False`... I was just surprised that both forms didn't have the same underlying representation (I thought `Style["aString", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 24]` would auto-evaluate to `Style["aString", Bold, 24]` or something like that).

Comment: @rm-rf So you'd like `Equal[var2,var1]` to evaluate to `True` in the same way that `Equal[1,1.0]` evaluates. I can see that.  But, are there other situations where `Equal[a,b]` evaluates to `True` where `a` and `b` are non-identical, non-numeric expressions? I'm not sure off the top of my head, but I haven't been thinking about code so much lately.  It's a little far afield of the OP's intention, perhaps. :)

Comment: No, I don't think there's such a situation for `Equal` either.  While `1` and `1.0` is a fine example, they are fundamentally different objects. However, `var1` and `var2` are exactly the same except in how they were defined. I suppose a simpler version of my question would be: "How can you robustly compare two styled strings?"